# Proving for $a>1,b > 1$, $2^a \ne p^b + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

Let $a>1,b>1,p$ be integers with $p$ an odd prime.

I am trying to find a concise way to show that $2^a \ne p^b+1$.

Is this a valid way to prove it?  Is there a better way or more standard way?

Here is my argument:

(1)  Assume that $2^a = p^b + 1$

(2)  $b$ is odd

> Since $a \ge 2$, $p^b \equiv -1 \pmod 4$ which is only possible if $p \equiv -1 \pmod 4$ and $b$ is odd.

(3)  Since $b \ge 3$, it follows that:

$$2^a = (p+1)(p^{b-1} - p^{b-2} + \dots + 1)$$

(4)  $p^{b-1} - p^{b-2} + \dots + 1 = \frac{p^b+1}{p+1} > 1$

> $(p^b + 1) - (p + 1) = p(p^{b-1} - 1) > 1$ so that $p^b+1 > p+1$

(5)  But now we have a contradiction because:

> - $p^{b-1} - p^{b-2} + \dots + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$  since $b-1$ is even
> - $p^{b-1} - p^{b-2} + \dots + 1 > 1$

---

Edit:  Made change based on comment received.

—-

Edit 2:  In my first edit, I asked an additional question which is clearly wrong.  I have removed the additional question.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, so forgive me if I've overlooked something obvious: in Step 2 how do you know that $b$ must be odd?

Comment: I do see that $3 \mid (2^a - 1)$ if $a$ is even, but that doesn't seem sufficient to prove that $2^a - 1$ is an Achilles number.

Comment: Here's my thinking.  Since $p^b \equiv -1 \pmod 4$, it follows that $p \equiv -1 \pmod 4$.  If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $p^b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$  Since $p \equiv -1 \pmod 4$, $b$ must be odd.  Otherwise, $p^b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Comment: Why would (5) yield a contradiction?

Comment: If a factor greater than $1$ divides a power of $2$, it needs to be even.  An odd factor is impossible

Comment: Oh, right, got it. I was looking at those two statements alone.

Comment: If the introduced $w$ can be odd wouldn't that resolve the problem of (5)? Say if you choose $w=p^{b-1}+p^{b-2}+\cdots+1$.

Comment: Yes.  I agree.  My supposition is wrong.  The argument only holds for a power of $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is ok until $\frac{p^b + 1}{p+1} > 1$ which is almost obviously, but I would put a little more efort to prove this. Say $$\frac{p^b + 1}{p+1}\geq \frac{p^2 + 1}{p+1} > 1$$
since $p^2>p$.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll add details to make this point more clear.